# How do I remove old versions of node/npm?

Tags: node.js, npm

I've been playing around with node a couple of months ago, as it's a fast evolving project, I thought I'd need to update it when I picked it up recently, not knowing how and having read about [n](https://github.com/visionmedia/n), I installed that, installed the latest version.

Everything was OK until I tried to use `npm`, which wouldnt work, see [this issue](https://github.com/visionmedia/n/issues/63).

So I needed to remove n, I didn't know how so instead removed all the versions of node I had installed using `n - {version}` for each version I had.

I then ran the installer straight off the node.js website, hoping it would fix all the issues I'm having.

Node now works as expected, but `npm` is *still* not working.

The error that is shown in `npm-debug.log` when trying `npm install {package}` is :

```
ERR! Error: EISDIR, mkdir '/'
ERR! You may report this log at:
ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
ERR! or email it to:
ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>
ERR!
ERR! System Darwin 11.3.0
ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm"
ERR! cwd /
ERR! node -v v0.6.15
ERR! npm -v 1.1.16
ERR! path /
ERR! code EISDIR
ERR! message EISDIR, mkdir '/'
ERR! errno {}
```

What I'm trying to do is re-install node + npm and start all over again.

I'm using a Mac, and have little experience with the commandline + file system in general with  OS X, still trying to adjust from the Windows way.. (Control panel -> Uninstall -> ....).

Any help with this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Could you give it a shot with [this script](http://npmjs.org/install.sh) from the [npm site](http://npmjs.org/)?

It should clean up any old installations you have and install the latest version.

Comment: "this script" hyperlink is broken.

Comment: @Irregardless It is not, but the download may get blocked by your browser or AV since it is a script.

Answer (score 0):

To [remove all cached versions except the current version](https://www.npmjs.com/package/n#removing-versions)

```
sudo n prune
```

Check how much all those versions are taking with `du -sh /usr/local/n/versions`.

Also,

> Remove the installed node and npm (does not affect the cached version). This can be useful to revert to the system version of node (if in a different location), or if you no longer wish to use node and npm, or are switching to a different way of managing them.

```
sudo n uninstall
```