# Stuck on an older version after installed a new one

Tags: node.js

```
node --version
v4.5.0

npm --version
2.15.9

node-gyp --version
v3.4.0

which node
/home/admin/.nvm/versions/node/v4.5.0/bin/node
```

For some reason, after running `sudo npm install -g node-gyp` - node-gyp installs with node v0.10.25:

```
npm WARN engine cryptiles@2.0.5: wanted: {"node":">=0.10.40"} (current: {"node":"v0.10.25","npm":"1.3.10"})
npm WARN engine boom@2.10.1: wanted: {"node":">=0.10.40"} (current: {"node":"v0.10.25","npm":"1.3.10"})
npm WARN engine hoek@2.16.3: wanted: {"node":">=0.10.40"} (current: {"node":"v0.10.25","npm":"1.3.10"})
```

I've accessed `/home/admin/.nvm/versions/node/` and found those folders: `v4.4.4, v4.4.7, v4.5.0`.

Can someone trigger the issue ? Where is that v0.10.25 version and how do I get rid of it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you, *as a normal user*, are using [`nvm`](https://github.com/creationix/nvm), Node Version Manager, which allows you to install different (newer/older) versions of Node independently of the system-installed version of Node (which, in your case, is 0.10.25).

When you install `node-gyp` using `sudo`, you're "switching" to a different user (root), for which the nvm setup doesn't apply. Hence, the system-installed version of Node will be used, triggering the error you're getting.

You have a few solutions:

- Don't use `sudo` when installing `node-gyp`. Because you're using `nvm`, you already have all the permissions required to install it as a normal user.
- Update the system-installed version of Node. It depends on which distribution you're using if this is possible; some Linux distro's only offer wildly outdated versions of Node in their main distribution. In that case, take a look at the [Nodesource binary distribution](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions), which provides recent Node binaries for the most common Linux distributions.

Comment: will the old version be removed if I would re-install it using the following command: 
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs

Comment: @ohadinho I think it will, yes.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to clean/remove the other versions of Node. Perhaps the easiest is to remove everything and then install afresh. There's a script (`install.sh`) for this on [npmjs.org site](http://npmjs.org/install.sh). Simply run this on your terminal and then it should remove any old installations and install the latest version.

Give it a try and let me know if this helps. It seems to have worked for closely related problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10364884/how-do-i-remove-old-versions-of-node-npm).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. i found that i had a node.exe file with old version, and in the PATH (environment variables) i had a link to this old node.exe folder. once removing it from the path (and restarting cmd) the problem was fixed