# node 8.4.0 already installed - But node -v shows v7.7.4

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, homebrew

I tried to upgrade my Node version, I downloaded the file from their website, run through the installation and everything seemed OK.

When I tried to check if the latest version has been installed, `node -v` showed me `v7.7.4` instead of `v8.4.0`.

I tried `brew upgrade node` but it told me `node 8.4.0 is already installed`.

How do I switch to the latest version?
Thanks!

Comment: And how is this related to programmin?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove old versions of node/npm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10364884/how-do-i-remove-old-versions-of-node-npm)

Comment: Did you previously install Node.js through Homebrew? Also, you say that `which node` _returns a path to the old version_. What's that, exactly?

Comment: @robertklep I don't remember how I installed it last time, I think I downloaded the file. `which node` returns `/Users/myname/.nvm/versions/node/v7.7.4/bin/node`

Comment: It's pretty obvious you installed it through `nvm` last time

Comment: Okay, so you're using `nvm` to manage Node.js versions. Try `nvm alias default system`

Comment: @PatrickRoberts he used the official installer. I use that myself to install the system-wide version of Node, but I also like to use `nvm` to manage older/newer versions. However, it's set to use the system-wide Node as default.

Comment: @robertklep ah, you should probably make that an answer then. I'll delete my suggestion since yours seems more appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `nvm` to install multiple versions of Node.js, and it looks like you set 7.7.4 as the default version of Node that `nvm` should use, which means that even though the system-wide version of Node is 8.4.0, `nvm` will insert the path to the 7.7.4 executable earlier in `$PATH`.

You can change the default to point to the system-wide version:

```
nvm alias default system
```

FWIW, Homebrew (`brew`) is *yet* another method of installing Node. However, given the amount of issues I see being posted here on StackOverflow related to that particular install, I wouldn't advise using it. Use the official installer to install the system-wide Node, and use `nvm` to manage different versions (for instance, to test your code with).

Answer (score -2):

you  can  check  your  installation directory
Command : 'where  node '

Comment: It tells me where: command not found.
When I run 'which node', it gives me a path to the old version

Comment: @Al-josh use `which`, not `where`